# Folder Sync with PST file when switching from POP to IMAP in Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, imap, pst

I'm using Outlook 365

I had Outlook connected via POP. I wanted to switch to IMAP.

I created a PST file with all my emails.

I then setup Outlook to use IMAP. Works fine.

I then imported my PST file. All my folder and emails appeared separately at the bottom on the left hand side under a separate heading. I dragged and dropped the folders into my IMAP account.

But they are not being copied over to the IMAP server even though all the folders are listed under the email account and I can view all my emails on the computer.

All the emails and folders are listed in Outlook. But when I connected to email with webmail none of them are showing.

How do I get Outlook to sync or copy all those emails and folders to the IMAP server?

Thanks!

---

The folders are not selectable. Its not working. All these folder are in the Inbox on the local computer in outlook which is setup with IMAP but they are not being uploaded to the IMAP server. When I log into my webmail none of them are there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

- use copy/paste commands
- use drag & drop
- import direct into the imap inbox folder

Wait for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Send/Receive Groups tab > Define Send/Receive Groups > Edit
  [image]
  [image]
- Check the button "Use the custom behavior defined below" and select the folders and subfolders that need to be synchronized.

[image]

- Right-click on the IMAP account and click Update Folder list.
  [image]

Comment: Its' not working, See my post with screenshot. i can't select any of the folders.

Comment: What about creating a new profile and readding your account?